# How can I add " character to a multi line string declaration in C#?

Tags: c#, string, escaping

If I write something like this:

```
string s = @"...."......";
```

it doesn't work.

---

If I try this:

```
string s = @"...\".....";
```

it doesn't work either.

How can I add a " character to a multi line string declaration in C#?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Try this:

```
string s = @"..."".....";
```

Comment: Hm, compiler does not complain now. :) But how does it work? Double "" has some special meaning when inside a string declaration?

Comment: When dealing with literal strings (the ones prefixed with "@") then you use the double-quote to escape itself instead of a backslash.

Comment: and how to remove it while saving in database? I just want to remove additional double quote used for escaping and not both

Comment: funny that Microsoft uses CSV RFC-4180 style to escape where should be \ and uses javascript escape \ notation in CSV files instead of  RFC-4180 like in DataFactoy CSV setting has escape string choice of \ while it should be always a standard `"`

Answer (score 11):

The double character usage also works with the characters <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> when you're using `string.Format` and you want to include a literal instance of either rather than indicate a parameter argument, for example:

```
string jsString = string.Format(
    "var jsonUrls = {{firstUrl: '{0}', secondUrl: '{1}'}};",
    firstUrl,
    secondUrl
    );
```

Comment: I was just thinking about other characters. You guessed it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

If in your case you need to use multiple lines with double quotes try this:

```
string s = @"
    SELECT id as ""Id""
    ";
```

Answer (score -3):

string `s = "...\".....";`  should work

the @ disables escapes so if you want to use \" then no @ symbol

Personally i think you should go with

```
string s = string.format("{0}\"{1},"something","something else");
```

it makes it easier in the long run

Comment: There is no need to format anything. Was just a multiline SQL query in code which I was trying to fix.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: they asked if there was a way to ignore escape char in a string and that is what I answered

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is about **multiline** strings.

Comment: @ANeves, Stephen Lujan mentioned that already but I will be sure to tell myself next time I travel back to 2017